# Different background images on different sites

Tags: images, custom-background

I use wordpress 4.0.5 and Minamaze Theme (https://wordpress.org/themes/minamaze)

The Minamaze Theme gives me the opportunity to add custom CSS, without having to edit any files, so I added:

```
body, #body-core {
background: url(http://leona-anderson.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/background40.png) fixed;
background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Adding this CSS sets the background properly. What I want to achieve now is, having differnt (like 2 or 3) background images on different pages.

Has anybody an idea how I could do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Depends on how the Minamaze theme allows for the extra CSS, and that makes the question off topic as being dependent upon third party code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look in the source code, and you'll see the body tag on every page and/or post has a unique class associated with it (postid-1241 for example).

Select that class and change the background image there.

Example:

```css
body.postid-1241 {
    background: url(http://example.com/bg.png) fixed;
}
```

Comment: You are right this works, thanks for that input :)